# Trying to create a custom block in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am new to stackoverflow but i will be very open with my doubt and questions which i want to ask.

I am trying to create  a custom block in magento. I am newbie to magento and learning it to become a advanced developer of magento.

I have tried the following things:

1. I have created a directory Magentotutorial in magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial.
2. I have made a basic structure in it which are five directory in Magentotutorial. So 
   the location is  magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World

Directories are :

```
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/controllers,
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/sql,
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/Model,
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/Helper,
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/Block,
magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/etc.
```

3. My config.xml goes into `magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/etc/config.xml`

config.xml file contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_World>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_World>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <Magentotutorial_World>
                <class>Magentotutorial_World_Block</class>
            </Magentotutorial_World>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Magentotutorial_World>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </Magentotutorial_World>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

To activate my module in magento i have created xml file.

Magentotutorial_World.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_World>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_World>
    </modules>
</config>
```

4. In my Block directory which is in `magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/Block`
   i have creted a file named example.php

example.php has the following code:

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_World_Block_Example extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

5. Now i have layout and template in my magento directory at`magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout`
In my layout file i have made test.xml file which has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
            <block type="magentotutorial_world/example" name="newreferenceBlock" template="test/example.phtml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

6. I have made a example.phtml file in test folder which is at the location  magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/test/example.phtml

example.phtml has the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

7. Now in page.xml i have put this code

   ```
   <default translate="label" module="page">
       <label>All Pages</label>



       <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

           <block type="magentotutorial_world/example" output="toHtml" name="newReferenceBlock" template="test/example.phtml" />

           <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
               <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
               <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
   ```

Over here i have put out my code which is

```
<block type="magentotutorial_world/example" output="toHtml" name="newReferenceBlock" template="test/example.phtml" />
```

8. Now i want to render this template to any layout of my page. I have here tried it for 2columns-right.phtml file.

in this file i have used getChildHtml.

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreferenceBlock'); ?></div>
```

The whole file is

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
                <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
                <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
<div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreferenceBlock') ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am Not able to render this block on any of my pages. Basically i want to add this template on my index page.

What is going wrong in my code?? I also want to know that is my block type ="magentotutorial_world" is right??

What if i want to revert changes in my test.xml and want to make changes in my page.xml file. 
How to do that???

Kindly help me out.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped block set in `magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/World/etc/config.xml`. Change `Magentotutorial_World` to lowercased `magentotutorial_world`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_World>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_World>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <magentotutorial_world>
                <class>Magentotutorial_World_Block</class>
            </magentotutorial_world>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Magentotutorial_World>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </Magentotutorial_World>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your block type should be

`<block type="world/example" output="toHtml" name="newReferenceBlock" template="test/example.phtml" />`

Correct me if i was wrong.